# How do I put more than one JSON instance in a single JSON object using net.sf.json.JSONObject library

Tags: java, json, json-lib

```
 //create the JSON Object to pass to the client
 JSONObject object=new JSONObject();

 //one instance
 object.put("name","something2");
 object.put("status", "up");

 //second instance
 object.put("name", "something2");
 object.put("status", "down");

 String json = object.toString();  

 response.getOutputStream().print(json);

 System.out.println("JSON Contents: "+json);
```

**Desired output: {name: something1, status: up}, {name: something2, status: down}... etc**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have JSONArray :

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(); jsonarray.add(object)...
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `{name: something1, status: up}, {name: something2, status: down}`, which is not valid JSON, I recommend targeting an array structure, such as `[{name: something1, status: up}, {name: something2, status: down}]`.  So, you'd build this with `net.sf.json.JSONArray`, adding `JSONObjects`, built similarly to what you've already got.  Of course, you'd need to change it to make two different `JSONObjects`, each of which would have the elements "name" and "status" added only once each.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you'd have to use `JSONArray` instead.

```
List<Map> list = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
Map map1 = new HashMap();  
map1.put("name","something");  
Map map2 = new HashMap();  
map2.put("status", "up"); 
list.add(map1);
list.add(map2);

JSONArray array = JSONArray.fromObject(list);  
String json = array.toString();  
System.out.println("JSON: "+ json);
```